# Python SqlAlchemy label comparison subquery

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Please help me in my mission to translate a raw query to SqlAlchemy specific and use **label** or **alias** to get column as a Bool out of a comparison.

What I cannot figure out is how to use label to get the same functionality as, **AS** from a raw SQL query:

from SQL: `currentMeeting.id > 0 as current` 
to SqlAlchemy: `(current_meeting.c.id > 0).label('current')`

to get a new column called **current** in my response

Raw SQL:

```
SELECT  meeting.*, currentMeeting.id > 0 as current \
                            FROM meeting \
                            LEFT JOIN( \
                            SELECT * \
                            FROM meeting \
                            WHERE meeting_date > now() \
                            ORDER BY meeting_date asc limit 1) currentMeeting \
                            ON currentMeeting.id = meeting.id \
                            WHERE meeting.id = {0}".format(meeting_id)
```

SqlAlchemy query (I get the results without the desired extra column **current**):

```
current_meeting = db.session.query(Meeting). \
        filter(Meeting.meeting_date > func.now()). \
        order_by(asc(Meeting.meeting_date)). \
        limit(1). \
        subquery('current_meeting')

meeting_obj = db.session.query(Meeting, (current_meeting.c.id > 0).label('current')). \
        outerjoin(current_meeting, Meeting.id == current_meeting.c.id). \
        filter(Meeting.id == meeting_id). \
        order_by(Meeting.id). \
        first()[0]
```

Comment: You have `meeting_obj = ....first()[0]`, or in other words you extract the first column of the result tuple only. Either remove the item access `[0]` and access the results using labels like `.Meeting` and `.current`, or unpack the result tuple: `meeting_obj, current = ....first()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were a life saver. It just works! Can you please add your comment as an answer to be able to up-vote. Tx.